# Graphics card in laptop not working

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have a Samsung NP880Z5E (IntelHD and Radeon 8700M) that I recently updated to Windows 10. After doing that, the brightness stopped working as was stuck at 50%. I fixed that issue by changing the driver for the IntelHD 4000 display adapter in Device Manager to Windows Basic Display Adapter. But once I did that, the Radeon 8700M has not worked. On this laptop, that HDMI port is attached to that card, and it is no longer responsive. I can plug in a monitor but it will not recognize it.

- Switching back to the IntelHD 4000 driver had no effect.
- Uninstalling the AMD driver with Display Driver Uninstaller, than
  reinstalling the latest driver had no effect.
- Disabling and re-enabling the drivers in device manager had no effect.
- There is no option for graphics cards in the BIOS.
- Radeon Settings > Sytem says the hardware is disabled, while the display adapter in Device Manager is enabled.
- There used to be an option on desktop right-click for configuring switchable graphics, but that is no longer present.

It seems as if when I switched the display adapter to fix the brightness issue, it disconnected my Radeon somehow.

Update: doing a factory restore (Laptop now has windows 8) did not resolve the issue. Next I am going to try and reset the BIOS by opening the laptop and removing the CMOS battery.

Comment: You know removing the CMOS battery is pretty much the same thing as a bios factory reset, you're just repeating the same thing via hardware that you did before with software.

Comment: Mmh, worth mentioning that sometimes the settings get corrupt in a way that a battery pull will fix but a factory settings reset will not. It isn't intuitive, but I've seen it work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the classic bugfest that is Windows 10. As with many other Windows issues (on any version of Windows), the easiest and simplest way to fix this might be to reinstall Windows 10, install the Intel driver you want to use, then install the Radeon driver and hope for the best.

But before you do that, make sure to thoroughly purge the AMD driver and reinstall it (boot into safe mode, and remove the Radeon driver both through uninstall software manager and through the device manager, then for good measure disable the card, restart and boot normally, then reinstall the radeon driver again and see if it just works after that, this can sometimes work) if that doesn't work, the one thing I can think of is a complete reinstall.

It is not exactly strange that your installation may have become corrupted after an upgrade from one version of windows to another so radically different, things are bound to work a little better on a clean Windows 10 install, as much of a pain that may be.

Comment: The real fix for this problem is to just not use Windows 10 though ;) (Whether that be going back to 8, or back to 7, or going to another OS, like Linux, where you're inevitably bound to run into all sorts of other problems... but at least not this one!)